# JPG continues to appear in subsequent pages

Tags: epub, calibre, conversion, image, epub-reader

I have tables I converted to jpg inserted into the MS Word file of a book to be published. After converting to epub with Calibre, I noticed the jpgs continue to show in the background in pages after the one they were inserted when the epub is viewd in Aldiko. They shadow the next 3 to 5 subsequent pages making them unreadable.

I googled & read around but couldn't get a way to stop this. I need help

Answer (score 1):

After much trial, I finally got round the problem by breaking paragraph after each image.